# Shipping weights - Metric vs English

Tags: shipping

We currently are setting up several stores, one of the stores needs to use the metric system and one needs to use the English system for weights...

Where can I specify Metric for one and English for the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no units settings in Magento, you will need to be creative with localization csv files to show correct symbols.
If you want to have units converted, you will have to look for a module that does that or create it your self.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the scope of the weight attribute to be store/website based from it's default global. This will then allow you to setup the weight based on the store.

If you only want to set in 1 unit of measurement (e.g. lbs) and then have the system convert automatically for other stores then you would need a customisation to support this. We have for instance done this where customers want to use Fedex in Europe and US but dont want to re-specify weights.